# In cmake, how can I always execute a process? (or capture stdout from add_custom_command)

Tags: cmake, catkin, cmake-custom-command

I am using generated files in my cmake project. I have a script that generates source code from some input, and the same script can also validate the input, if given a different command line argument, like this:

`generate_code.py --generate`

`generate_code.py --validate`

The `--validate` mode will print errors to `stdout` if the input is not valid, and I would like to have those errors visible. My current setup is to run with `--validate` in an `execute_process` and with `--generate` in an `add_custom_command`. This works, but doesn't print the user-friendly error messages from the `--validate` mode when the input changes, because the `execute_process` doesn't run again.

What would be the best way to surface these errors? If I could force `execute_process` to always run, that would work, or if I could capture `stdout` when `--generate` fails and surface that, I could modify the `--generate` option to print friendly error messages, and then display them. How can I do one or both of those?

Answer (score 1):

Commands in [add_custom_target statements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) are re-run every time the build is executed as long as you pass the `ALL` argument.  This may be what you are looking for.

Alternatively, you could make the inputs to `generate_code.py` be dependencies of the custom command (if they aren't already), and have the custom command execute `generate_code.py --validate` before `generate_code.py --generate`.  That way it would get revalidated when it needs to be rebuilt, and not at any other time.

Comment: That seems promising. Only revalidating when I need to rebuild would be great. Do you know how I can capture the `stdout` of the custom command so I can display it when validation fails?

Comment: I think that you are getting confused between commands run at **CMake-generate** time and commands run at **build time**.  You can capture the stdout of commands run by `execute_process` because CMake runs those commands when you run the CMake script.  You cannot capture output from `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` because those commands are run by `make` at build time.  If you really need to capture that output, what you _could_ do is write a CMake script that uses `execute_process` and invoke it by using `add_custom_command` to execute `cmake -P`

Comment: However, what I'd recommend would be to have `generate_code.py --validate` return an error exit code when validation fails and print the results to the screen.  This way, `make` would see the fault code and stop the build, and you would be able to see the error message that was printed.